# How to implement server side screen capture with Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, screenshot, chromium, screen-capture

I am building a site that can take web page screen capture of the given URL, and then output a image URL. There have been so many services like this, but I am curious about how it works.

Initially, I guess I have to execute a browser on server-side, feed the URL given from client. The browser then load the URL, after that, wait for a few seconds for executing javascript because some pages cost time to perform its UI, like Trello. In the end, call certain API to capture that page.

I made up my mind to using the open source browser, Chromium. Even so, I still have doubt about if I am doing the right thing.

### Questions

1. Does my direction right?
2. I am wondering how to execute a long-live Chromium browser on my server.
3. Is there a shell I can control Chromium in command line?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has a built in API that may meet your needs "captureVisibleTab":

> chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(integer windowId, object options, function callback)
>
> Captures the visible area of the currently active tab in the specified window. You must have host permission for the URL displayed by the tab.

http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/tabs.html#method-captureVisibleTab